# Reducing 1 1/2" conduit to 1/2" liquid tight

Tags: electrical, conduit

I'm running multiple wires through the same PVC conduit pipe (1.5") that need to exit into flexible liquid tight that is (0.5").  I'm not seeing any reducers for doing something like this other than white plumbing connectors.

**Here is the "T" I was planning on using:**

[image]

**Here is the liquid tight:**

[image]

Can this be done up to code?  What are my alternatives if it cant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've only seen liquid tight with threaded connections, like this:

[image]

So basically you need to go from 1 1/2" to 1/2" threaded.

There are reducing bushings, like this:

[image]

Finding 1 1/2" to 1/2" seems to be difficult (that's a big drop) -- but they do exist (I can find them in catalogs, just can't find an actual picture).

If you can get a 1" or 3/4" to 1/2" (much more likely) then you just also need a reducing bushing (or two) to go from 1 1/2" to that size:

[image]

---

Another way to make the connection is to use a 1/2" female adapter on the end of a short piece of PVC pipe:

[image]

Again, you'd have to use bushings to get from the 1 1/2" box to the 1/2" PVC pipe.

---

Be sure to use PVC cement to make the connections and keep it water-tight.

Comment: Awesome I could not tell what it was on my phone and did not see a single  PVC reducer but I believe you are right on the fitting for liquid tight Killing my answer since I thought it was a metal T. +

Answer (score 3):

Terminate the PVC conduit to a blank PVC Box.

[image: blank boxes]

Right, you'll also need a box adapter to do that termination

[image: Box adapter]

Drill a hole, glue in, with a female fitting on the outside of the box glued to this (holds it firmly in place.)

Use the first fitting type Ed's answer shows.

[image: fitting with nut]

Drill (normal, unthreaded) holes in the box, use the nut to hold it in place. There's even a dandy yellow gasket to keep it sealed.

Comment: Could I drill a hole in this?  https://hw.menardc.com/main/items/media/THOMA018/ProductLarge/TypeC_ConduitBody.jpg

Comment: You could drill a hole in it, but it's of marginal size (volume) for a junction box, most likely. It will probably have a volume marked and you can do the math on that part.